# How to handle if no file is uploaded in Shiny App

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am working on a `Shiny` application that includes three main features:

- Uploading an .xlsx file.
- Processing the uploaded file when a `Process` button is clicked.
- Downloading the  .xlsx file when a  `Download` button is clicked.

But the above buttons needs to be based on two conditions:

- When a user tries to click the `Download` button without uploading a
  file, a pop up message should show.
- If the user uploads a file but clicks the `Download` button without
  first clicking the "Process" button, the application should display a
  pop-up message.
- if all above conditions are met and `Download` button is pressed then xlsx file should be downloaded

In my current implementation, the pop-up message does not display when the `Download` button is clicked without first uploading a file. However, after a file is uploaded, clicking the 'Download' button does work as expected. In addition to that, `process` button condition is also not added.

My sample Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

library(writexl)

library(bsplus)

library(shinyalert)
library(shinyjs)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Regularizer 15 min"),
  tags$div(id = "sidebar",
           sidebarPanel(
             bs_accordion(
               id = "accordion"
             ) %>%  
               bs_set_opts(
                 use_heading_link = TRUE
               ) %>%  
               bs_append(
                 title = tags$div(tags$i(class = "fa-solid fa-upload"),"Upload"),
                 content = fileInput("upload", "Upload a Excel File",  
                                     accept = c(".xlsx",".csv"))
               ),
             actionButton("act_button1", "Process"), # You may need to specify the action of this button
             use_bs_accordion_sidebar()
           )),
  mainPanel(id = "mainPanel",
            tags$div(class = "download-btn",
                     downloadButton("downloadData_all", "Download Regularized ")
            )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)
  
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$downloadData_all, {
    if (is.null(input$upload)){
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Error",
        "Click Process ",
        footer = NULL, easyClose = TRUE
      ))
    } 
  })
  
  output$downloadData_all <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      file_name <- input$upload$name
      paste("regularised_", file_name, ".xlsx", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      req(input$upload)
      
      data <- readxl::read_excel(input$upload$datapath, sheet = 1)
      
      
      writexl::write_xlsx(data, path = file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui,  server)
```

Comment: It would be easier to disable the buttons.

Comment: I think disable is much more easier. I had a success on that functionality. But from a user side which would be better disable button or pop up message?

Comment: Better to disable and to add a tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

As @Stéphane Laurent suggests here is a disabled button, that enables only the previous steps are fulfilled:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)
library(bsplus)
library(shinyalert)
library(shinyjs)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyalert::useShinyalert(), #added
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Regularizer 15 min"),
  tags$div(id = "sidebar",
           sidebarPanel(
             bs_accordion(
               id = "accordion"
             ) %>%  
               bs_set_opts(
                 use_heading_link = TRUE
               ) %>%  
               bs_append(
                 title = tags$div(tags$i(class = "fa-solid fa-upload"),"Upload"),
                 content = fileInput("upload", "Upload an Excel File", accept = c(".xlsx",".csv"))
               ),
             actionButton("act_button1", "Process", disabled = TRUE),
             use_bs_accordion_sidebar()
           )),
  mainPanel(id = "mainPanel",
            tags$div(class = "download-btn",
                     downloadButton("downloadData_all", "Download Regularized", disabled = TRUE) #added disabled = TRUE
            )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)
  
  data_processed <- reactiveVal(FALSE) # added reactive value to check if data is processed

    
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$upload)){
      shinyjs::enable("act_button1")
    }
  })
 
  # added button action and logic as observe event  
  observeEvent(input$act_button1, {
    data_processed(TRUE)
    shinyjs::enable("downloadData_all")
  })
  
  # added button action and logic as observe event  
  observeEvent(input$downloadData_all, {
    if(is.null(input$upload)){
      shinyalert::shinyalert("Error", "Please upload a file before downloading.", type = "error")
    } else if (!data_processed()) {
      shinyalert::shinyalert("Error", "Click Process before downloading.", type = "error")
    }
  })
  
  output$downloadData_all <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      file_name <- input$upload$name
      paste("regularised_", file_name, ".xlsx", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      req(input$upload)
      
      data <- readxl::read_excel(input$upload$datapath, sheet = 1)
      writexl::write_xlsx(data, path = file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: When I upload new file after uploading a file. The download button is still enabled without clicking process button.

Comment: Try adding `observeEvent(input$upload, {data_processed(FALSE); shinyjs::disable("downloadData_all")})`