# Issue with the process flow of reuploading a file

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple app with three buttons: "Upload", "Process", and "Download".

The "Upload" button allows users to upload an Excel file.
Until an Excel file is uploaded, the "Process" and "Download" buttons are disabled.
Once a file is uploaded, the "Process" button is enabled.
After clicking "Process", the "Download" button becomes enabled, allowing users to download the Excel file.
However, I'm facing an issue:

After processing and downloading the first file, if I upload a new file, the "Download" button remains enabled for this new file. I want it to be disabled until the new file is processed.

Example Code:

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)
library(bsplus)
library(shinyalert)
library(shinyjs)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyalert::useShinyalert(), #added
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Regularizer 15 min"),
  tags$div(id = "sidebar",
           sidebarPanel(
             bs_accordion(
               id = "accordion"
             ) %>%  
               bs_set_opts(
                 use_heading_link = TRUE
               ) %>%  
               bs_append(
                 title = tags$div(tags$i(class = "fa-solid fa-upload"),"Upload"),
                 content = fileInput("upload", "Upload an Excel File", accept = c(".xlsx",".csv"))
               ),
             actionButton("act_button1", "Process", disabled = TRUE),
             use_bs_accordion_sidebar()
           )),
  mainPanel(id = "mainPanel",
            tags$div(class = "download-btn",
                     downloadButton("downloadData_all", "Download Regularized", disabled = TRUE) #added disabled = TRUE
            )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)
  
  data_processed <- reactiveVal(FALSE) # added reactive value to check if data is processed

    
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$upload)){
      shinyjs::enable("act_button1")
    }
  })
 
  # added button action and logic as observe event  
  observeEvent(input$act_button1, {
    data_processed(TRUE)
    shinyjs::enable("downloadData_all")
  })
  
  # added button action and logic as observe event  
  observeEvent(input$downloadData_all, {
    if(is.null(input$upload)){
      shinyalert::shinyalert("Error", "Please upload a file before downloading.", type = "error")
    } else if (!data_processed()) {
      shinyalert::shinyalert("Error", "Click Process before downloading.", type = "error")
    }
  })
  
  output$downloadData_all <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      file_name <- input$upload$name
      paste("regularised_", file_name, ".xlsx", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      req(input$upload)
      
      data <- readxl::read_excel(input$upload$datapath, sheet = 1)
      writexl::write_xlsx(data, path = file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This code was from [How to handle if no file is uploaded in Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76843924/how-to-handle-if-no-file-is-uploaded-in-shiny-app/76845267#76845267)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `observe()` statement to an `observeEvent()` which sets the reactive `data_processed` to FALSE everytime a new document is uploaded and include a statement to disable the download button.

```
  observeEvent(input$upload, {
    data_processed(FALSE)
    shinyjs::enable("act_button1")
    shinyjs::disable("downloadData_all")
  })
```

See full code for running app below:

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)
library(bsplus)
library(shinyalert)
library(shinyjs)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyalert::useShinyalert(), #added
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Regularizer 15 min"),
  tags$div(id = "sidebar",
           sidebarPanel(
             bs_accordion(
               id = "accordion"
             ) %>%  
               bs_set_opts(
                 use_heading_link = TRUE
               ) %>%  
               bs_append(
                 title = tags$div(tags$i(class = "fa-solid fa-upload"),"Upload"),
                 content = fileInput("upload", "Upload an Excel File", accept = c(".xlsx",".csv"))
               ),
             actionButton("act_button1", "Process", disabled = TRUE),
             use_bs_accordion_sidebar()
           )),
  mainPanel(id = "mainPanel",
            tags$div(class = "download-btn",
                     downloadButton("downloadData_all", "Download Regularized", disabled = TRUE) #added disabled = TRUE
            )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)
  
  data_processed <- reactiveVal(FALSE) # added reactive value to check if data is processed
  
  observeEvent(input$upload, {
    data_processed(FALSE)
    shinyjs::enable("act_button1")
    shinyjs::disable("downloadData_all")
  })
  
  # added button action and logic as observe event  
  observeEvent(input$act_button1, {
    data_processed(TRUE)
    shinyjs::enable("downloadData_all")
  })
  
  # added button action and logic as observe event  
  observeEvent(input$downloadData_all, {
    if(is.null(input$upload)){
      shinyalert::shinyalert("Error", "Please upload a file before downloading.", type = "error")
    } else if (!data_processed()) {
      shinyalert::shinyalert("Error", "Click Process before downloading.", type = "error")
    }
  })
  
  output$downloadData_all <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      file_name <- input$upload$name
      paste("regularised_", file_name, ".xlsx", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      req(input$upload)
      
      data <- readxl::read_excel(input$upload$datapath, sheet = 1)
      writexl::write_xlsx(data, path = file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks!.
I have a new question it is that: So in my real shiny app, when I upload the excel file and click process a plot generates. But when I try to reupload the excel file the plot generates automatically without clicking the process button. (Do I need to post a new question for this).

Comment: It likely needs a reactive value as a condition. But hard to say without an example. But since this is a different issue, I would propose to accept this answer and ask a new question.